# Name collisions between layers

Tags: architecture, name-clash

So I'm developing a very cool (and very large) n-tier application.

Basically I have the following assemblies:

Domain
Domain.Contracts

Services
Services.Contracts

Presentation.Admin
Presentation.Web
Presentation.Core (shared between Admin & Web)
I may implement Presentation.Core.Contracts

**My main issue I'm wrestling with are name collisions between the different layers.**  Ie.

Services.Contracts.AccountServicesRequest
Domain.Contracts.AccountServicesRequest

I had the same issue with Service names (in this case I am just using classes as services rather than WCF, etc).  Ie:

Services.Contracts.IAccountService
Domain.Contracts.IAccountService

I resolved this by now making all "service handlers" in the domain layer IxxxServiceHandler which gives me this:

Services.Contracts.IAccountService
Domain.Contracts.IAccountServiceHandler

However, I haven't been able to resolve this issue with the objects that are passed back and forth between layers.
This seems to be sprinkled in a bunch of places through my solution(s).
I was just curious to see if anyone has had the same issues.  If so, how did you resolve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have run into this problem, but I have fixed it soon enough every time.

A good class naming convention can help. Avoid using the same name in classes across multiple layers.

Alternatively, you can use [namespace aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx), so that you would be using, for example:

```
services::IAccountService
domain::IAccountService
```

Does this help?

Comment: Haha!  Yes this does help but maybe you could give me an example.
Let's say (for simplicity) I have 3 layers:
(1) Domain\Domain.Contracts
(2) Services\Services.Contracts
(3) Presentation

If I have a User object in Domain and IUser and/or UserDto what would you name these objects in the other layers?

Comment: Well, I would need to know exactly *what* you are naming in order to determine the optimal name for it. :-) Things such as "Contract", "User", etc. sound very much like problem-domain concepts, which I would suggest to place in a single business-logic layer. You don't want to replicate these classes elsewhere. You could have classes such as Business.Contract and Business.User. (TBC)

Comment: On the presentation layer, you could have, for example, Presentation.ContractDialog or Presentation.UserWindow. A "contract dialog" is a dialog box that displays a contract; you wouldn't have Presentation.Contract because contracts themselves are modelled *only* in the business logic layer. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks CesarGon.  This does make sense.  After some studying / playing around I figured out how I'll do this.  My real issue was that I was passing dtos between the domain and services layers.  Instead I'm passing interfaces between domain and services layers and having the domain implementation internal.  Then I have a dto in the services layer which also implements the domain interface.  Thanks for your help.